# Delay HTML render with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to delay page render with jQuery so that all the appends and the jQuery files loads properly. Is it possible? If so, how can I delay page rendering?

I'm pretty new to jquery so not so experienced at this. Help is much appreciated!

**Problem**

I've created a layout switcher for blog posts on my site. To do that, I'm using localStorage which takes a few seconds to load. Then I run a if and else statement which adds an external CSS file on document.ready. That means, if a user loads a page, they can see the layout changing which I think is user unfriendly. So I want to delay the render by 20 seconds. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "all the appends", but in general this sounds like an issue with the order of loading of the scripts. What exact problem are you facing? Can you please add to the question some relevant parts of your html? Specially interesting are the places where `<script>`s are, both local blocks and access to external ones.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  How does this problem actually manifest itself?  What you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Did you mean that the page is shown after all append are done?

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated my question.

Comment: You want to read about the terms "asynchronous" and "callback"...

Comment: @MehediHassan: `"I'm using localStorage which takes a few seconds to load"` - That doesn't seem like an accurate statement.  What is the actual cause of the delay?  `"they can see the layout changing"` - Isn't that what is meant by "a layout switcher"?  Isn't the ability to *change the layout* exactly what the user is expecting to see?  It's still not clear what the problem is.  But "delaying for 20 seconds" doesn't sound like it's going to make for a very good UX either...

Comment: The localStorage function triggers on document.ready cause it's part of a WordPress theme and the jQuery doesn't work if it doesn't load on document.ready for some reason. I don't want to layout to change right way - it changes on page reload. But when a user visits the page again, they can see the layout changing as the CSS file is being loaded. What could be a faster way of doing it?

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pastee.org/ns8q2

Comment: @MehediHassan: `"But when a user visits the page again, they can see the layout changing as the CSS file is being loaded."` - If the CSS is taking a long time to render, that doesn't sound like it has much of anything to do with JavaScript. The browser has to render the styling, there's no way around that. Is the styling so complex that it slows down browsers somehow? How are you actually setting the CSS? If it happens "when a user visits the page again" then can't the server-side code simply specify the correct CSS file? If you could include *any* demonstration of the problem that would help.

Comment: @david Researched a bit, and found out that it would be quicker to use Cookies for this. I'll try cookies and see if it any faster than the current method. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of possible soulutins :

Hide everything on server with :

```
<body style="display: none;">...</body>
```

then, when localStorage is ready show all content :

```
$('body').show();
```

But this is bad one because visitor is not see any progress in background, better solution is to put `div` with loading message that covers everything and than just remove that `div`.

Comment: But that makes the pageload too slow which I don't want. I just want to delay render by 20 seconds.

Comment: @MehediHassan prepare that on server side (body hide or div that covers everything). That will be visible right away you don't have to wait.